# How to find a certain method from classes with the same simple name?

Tags: java, reflection

I have many ObjectFactory classes that reside in different packages.
They are all standalone classes, meaning that they don't extend from any class.
I cannot modify those classes.

**Now**, I need to provide an ObjectFactory to a command-handler class. This ObjectFactory must have a set of methods needed for this exact command-handler class.

How would I go on about scanning all the ObjectFactory classes from different packages to find one with the methods that I need?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing this is to *read* all the classes in the class path. Assuming that you have a specific package prefix - you can reduce the number of classes to scan.

Anyhow, look at [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections). You can get all classes with methods having some specific signature etc. with its help.